# Modal Window Not Showing Up But Background Fades out

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the button that brings up the modal:

```
<li><a href="#" class="hvr-bounce-to-right" data-target="#PrctcSched" data-toggle="modal" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Practice Schedule</a></li>
```

When I hit Practice Schedule button, the background fades out but the modal window does not show up.

Here's the modal code. Can you please see whats wrong with my code here?

```
<!-- Modal Practice Schedule Block Begin -->
<div class="modal" id="PrctcSched" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lblPrctcHdr" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close"
                   data-dismiss="modal">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="lblPrctcHdr">
                    My Availability
                </h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body Block Begin -->
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#" method="POST">

                  <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="chbxDt1" Id="chbxDt1" value="chbxDt1chkd" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            <label for="chbxDt1">1</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="chbxDt2" Id="chbxDt2" value="chbxDt2chkd" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            <label for="chbxDt2">2</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="chbxDt3" Id="chbxDt3" value="chbxDt3chkd" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            <label for="chbxDt3">3</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update My Availability</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>

                <!-- Modal Footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </button>
                </div>

            </div>
      <!-- Modal Body Block End -->



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put your code into a page i am working on and it works fine. you can add the "fade" class to it to ensure that the modal fades in rather than just appearing, but the link triggered the modal for me.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="PrctcSched"...
```

Check your version of bootstrap and ensure that you have jquery,bootstrap.js AND bootstrap.css in your document head.

Comment: Thanks GavGrif, That's whats surprising me too, cos I know the code looks right and in fact, I have a similar modal running on the same page, and it runs just fine!...I dont think there is a limit on the number of modals in a page, is there? By the way, thank you for the quick response.

Comment: one thought - check for a competing id - if there are two id's of "PrctcSched" then the first one will be the target - and may not be the modal - also your form action should not be "#" - use action ="" to allow the form to submit to the same page and reload it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply again. No competing IDs. This is really bugging me!